# EXC_BREAKPOINT on iOS5

Tags: crash, ios5

I've got EXC_BREAKPOINT exception occurred in the middle of work.

```
Date/Time:       2011-10-20 15:19:05.089 +0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000102, 0x355cf020
Crashed Thread:  11


Thread 11 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x355cefdc CFHash + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3564ac10 __CFDictionaryStandardHashKey + 16
2   CoreFoundation                  0x355cd9d8 CFBasicHashFindBucket + 1780
3   CoreFoundation                  0x355cd2ce CFDictionaryGetValue + 110
4   CoreFoundation                  0x355f09f4 _CFStreamDetachSource + 144
5   CoreFoundation                  0x355f02d6 _CFStreamClose + 62
6   CoreFoundation                  0x355f0be2 CFReadStreamClose + 98
7   CFNetwork                       0x31fc9b9c HTTPReadStream::dequeueRequestFromConnection(unsigned char) + 92
8   CFNetwork                       0x31fca3b4 HTTPReadStream::streamClose(__CFReadStream*) + 24
9   CoreFoundation                  0x355f02ca _CFStreamClose + 50
10  CoreFoundation                  0x355f0be2 CFReadStreamClose + 98
11  ИСЭД                            0x00139d60 -[ASIHTTPRequest startRequest] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:1323)
12  ИСЭД                            0x0013729c -[ASIHTTPRequest main] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:924)
13  ИСЭД                            0x001367e8 -[ASIHTTPRequest startSynchronous] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:772)
```

Have no idea why it can happened.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your debugger is not properly attatched to the process running on your device..

Plug off the device and plug it in again. If that doesn't work, reboot it.

You should also turn off WLAN-Sync within iTunes (breaks attatching to remote processes because XCode chooses the wrong connection to the device)

Comment: I run app on device not connected to debugger, xcode or even computer.

Comment: weird.. try clean and build in release configuration (e.g. archive)