# EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) On Application Startup

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, crash

I have an application that pulls in some RSS Feeds. I first load the app delegate which in turn loads a SplashScreenViewContoller which then figures out which feeds to pull in based on date.

This is all great. Everything has been working fine in the Simulator/iPad when running in Debug mode. I've now tried to create an Ad-Hoc app and the application crashes when I get to the SplashScreen.

I had an initial exception code error (Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d) that when Googling related to the launch time of the application but this has been resolved. This is the crash log dump of my latest problem.

Anyone have any ideas how I resolve this???

```
Incident Identifier: B4F5E7CE-963B-4CC0-BD6C-9FF3A8F37E83
CrashReporter Key:   3887854c6ae7a348803250fc0aa3c561e259f20e
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         My App [8302]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/29A2E76E-3C2F-41E6-8965-DE0B048FB15B/My App.app/My App
Identifier:      My App
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-04-16 16:02:39.351 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1 (9B176)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000102, 0x6e085801
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x369dae4c CFHash + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x36a56be0 __CFDictionaryStandardHashKey + 16
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36aa90ac __CFBasicHashAddValue + 840
3   CoreFoundation                  0x369dc1ac CFBasicHashSetValue + 3012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x369db5b4 CFDictionarySetValue + 192
5   CoreFoundation                  0x36a0eba6 -[CFXPreferencesSource setValue:forKey:] + 50
6   CoreFoundation                  0x36a19242 -[CFXPreferencesPropertyListSource setValue:forKey:] + 86
7   CoreFoundation                  0x36a19190 _CFXPreferencesSetValue + 128
8   CoreFoundation                  0x36a19082 CFPreferencesSetAppValue + 30
9   Foundation                      0x358eb456 -[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults) setObject:forKey:] + 78
10  My App                      0x0007741e +[MKStoreManager setObject:forKey:] (MKStoreManager.m:123)
11  My App                      0x00079a38 -[MKStoreManager rememberPurchaseOfProduct:] (MKStoreManager.m:608)
12  My App                      0x000796b0 -[MKStoreManager provideContent:forReceipt:] (MKStoreManager.m:584)
13  My App                      0x0007a25e -[MKStoreObserver restoreTransaction:] (MKStoreObserver.m:94)
14  My App                      0x00079f48 -[MKStoreObserver paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:] (MKStoreObserver.m:53)
15  StoreKit                        0x37ce77a0 __NotifyObserverAboutChanges + 52
16  CoreFoundation                  0x369e0af4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 32
17  StoreKit                        0x37ce775c -[SKPaymentQueue _notifyObserversAboutChanges:] + 112
18  StoreKit                        0x37ce7dee -[SKPaymentQueue _processUpdates:trimUnmatched:] + 1042
19  StoreKit                        0x37ce7026 -[SKPaymentQueue _transactionsRefreshedNotification:] + 42
20  Foundation                      0x359724f8 __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 12
21  CoreFoundation                  0x36a5d540 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 64
22  CoreFoundation                  0x369e9090 _CFXNotificationPost + 1400
23  Foundation                      0x358e63e4 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 60
24  AppSupport                      0x35017b9c -[CPDistributedNotificationCenter deliverNotification:userInfo:] + 56
25  AppSupport                      0x35019104 _CPDNDeliverNotification + 284
26  AppSupport                      0x35017994 _XDeliverNotification + 164
27  AppSupport                      0x3500cb0a migHelperRecievePortCallout + 166
28  CoreFoundation                  0x36a6551c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
29  CoreFoundation                  0x36a654be __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
30  CoreFoundation                  0x36a6430c __CFRunLoopRun + 1364
31  CoreFoundation                  0x369e749e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
32  CoreFoundation                  0x369e7366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
33  GraphicsServices                0x30ac9432 GSEventRunModal + 130
34  UIKit                           0x36d38e76 UIApplicationMain + 1074
35  My App                      0x00041434 main (main.m:14)
36  My App                      0x000413ec 0x40000 + 5100

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3725f3a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3146df04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3146dc22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3725f004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3725f1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36a653ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36a64124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x369e749e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x369e7366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   WebCore                         0x301dd0f0 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3384572e _pthread_start + 314
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x338455e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726f0d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33839674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   CoreData                        0x34ce3d52 -[_PFLock lock] + 18
3   CoreData                        0x34cf31f2 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 806
4   CoreData                        0x34d5b280 -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 516
5   My App                      0x00074472 -[SQCoreDataManager saveContext] (SQCoreDataManager.m:51)
6   My App                      0x000535fa -[ContentManager renewArticlesFromWebURL:sectionName:sectionIndex:] (ContentManager.m:567)
7   My App                      0x0005223a -[ContentManager main] (ContentManager.m:68)
8   Foundation                      0x3598758a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3384572e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x338455e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3725f004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3725f1fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x36a653ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x36a64124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x369e749e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x369e7366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x358f3bb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x358f3a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3598758a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3384572e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x338455e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726fcd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383ff36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3383fcc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3726f570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x36a6963a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3384572e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x338455e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x36a56bd1      r3: 0x3f6ff9a8
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x00277f60      r6: 0x00277f60      r7: 0x2fe3d9dc
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x00000012     r10: 0x00277f60     r11: 0x00000001
    ip: 0x369da6bd    sp: 0x2fe3d9d8      lr: 0x36a56be7      pc: 0x369dae4c
  cpsr: 0x600f0030

Binary Images:
   0x40000 -    0xddfff +My App armv7  <69c465def4683635a36a369fa5fbb9cc> /var/mobile/Applications/29A2E76E-3C2F-41E6-8965-DE0B048FB15B/My App.app/My App
0x2fe3f000 - 0x2fe60fff  dyld armv7  <4a817f3e0def30d5ae2032157d889c1d> /usr/lib/dyld
0x300a7000 - 0x300ecfff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x30132000 - 0x30133fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7850befd26b630f183ee326aaadd7b34> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x30134000 - 0x308f2fff  WebCore armv7  <814351ff217e3425a8e532c2e2251f73> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30ac5000 - 0x30acffff  GraphicsServices armv7  <e21a6e61bdd136b6805a9e3abe2e3d1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30ad4000 - 0x30b11fff  FTServices armv7  <28ed78e01a77388cb4c0f2f6ec33482c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x30c03000 - 0x30c19fff  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x30c1a000 - 0x30c1afff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x30c1b000 - 0x30c33fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x30c34000 - 0x30c37fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x30d9c000 - 0x30da0fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x30db9000 - 0x30e7ffff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30e84000 - 0x30ebcfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x30f1d000 - 0x3114afff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ec9bc89489763c6c93f86c5c490b2d69> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3114b000 - 0x3115cfff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3115d000 - 0x3115efff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3117f000 - 0x31180fff  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x31239000 - 0x3123efff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <2bb524b3bb3c3eb2932ce13b655b7c7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x31256000 - 0x3143afff  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3144d000 - 0x31453fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3146a000 - 0x31480fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x314c0000 - 0x314fcfff  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31510000 - 0x31514fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x31541000 - 0x31565fff  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31566000 - 0x3163dfff  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31c39000 - 0x31c3afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x31c3e000 - 0x31c88fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <5e0a131bbfec305ea01f9e01f486da63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x31d3b000 - 0x31d8cfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x31d8d000 - 0x31d95fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x31e01000 - 0x31e10fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x31e11000 - 0x31e14fff  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x31e7e000 - 0x31ebdfff  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x31ee7000 - 0x31f35fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x31f39000 - 0x31f69fff  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x31f84000 - 0x31f93fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <ca5b10014b473d2eaec5c48d89ee1b54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x31f94000 - 0x31fadfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x31fae000 - 0x31faefff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3201e000 - 0x32562fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x32607000 - 0x3263cfff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x32640000 - 0x32691fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32692000 - 0x32718fff  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32af7000 - 0x32afbfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x32afc000 - 0x32afdfff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x32b46000 - 0x32bfcfff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x32ec8000 - 0x32ed4fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x330f3000 - 0x33102fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x33304000 - 0x333f2fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x333f3000 - 0x33409fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3340a000 - 0x3340afff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x3340e000 - 0x33445fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x33553000 - 0x33559fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x3355a000 - 0x3381bfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x3381c000 - 0x33836fff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <cccdb5638b17398f8082542c1b3c8cf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
0x33837000 - 0x338c3fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x339a6000 - 0x339a6fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x33a13000 - 0x33a18fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33a19000 - 0x33a20fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x33ad7000 - 0x33b0cfff  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x33b60000 - 0x33b61fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x33c66000 - 0x33d8bfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33d8c000 - 0x33d91fff  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x33de6000 - 0x33de8fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33e0d000 - 0x33e56fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x33e59000 - 0x33e62fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x33e63000 - 0x33eaffff  CoreTelephony armv7  <e8eb52ca5fe33c7488a33efd222e7804> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33f1b000 - 0x33f21fff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x3400d000 - 0x34030fff  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34032000 - 0x340a2fff  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x340ae000 - 0x3426bfff  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3429e000 - 0x3429efff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x343e0000 - 0x34420fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x3446e000 - 0x3447afff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x345cb000 - 0x345d0fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x34605000 - 0x34649fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x346c4000 - 0x34738fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x34751000 - 0x347aefff  StoreServices armv7  <628fbbc73ed93730962c53bfbfde6794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x347af000 - 0x34855fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x34894000 - 0x349ddfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x349de000 - 0x349e8fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x34a92000 - 0x34b2bfff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x34b3c000 - 0x34b41fff  SyncedDefaults armv7  <99fe2106e10539ba8aedcacf52361d66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SyncedDefaults.framework/SyncedDefaults
0x34b6a000 - 0x34bcdfff  IMCore armv7  <6e26e99b9b5f3829a8486ffd8c64f0d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x34cdb000 - 0x34e81fff  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x34e83000 - 0x34e86fff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x34fcd000 - 0x35009fff  IMFoundation armv7  <77bb4365a65b32a49523b03da0340dbc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3500a000 - 0x35046fff  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x351a3000 - 0x351a7fff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x352f0000 - 0x352f4fff  IOSurface armv7  <6ae77a40f8e93f28bc466ca93f5675d4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x352f5000 - 0x3531efff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x35370000 - 0x35440fff  WebKit armv7  <6ff2796c2f933050ac6ecdee9fc6a216> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35649000 - 0x356f6fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x356f7000 - 0x356fafff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x3570d000 - 0x35730fff  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x3574a000 - 0x3577efff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x357ca000 - 0x357d9fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x357df000 - 0x357f4fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3580b000 - 0x3580dfff  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3584c000 - 0x35850fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x35851000 - 0x35855fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x35862000 - 0x35862fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3586f000 - 0x358b2fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x358b6000 - 0x358d6fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x358d9000 - 0x358ddfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x358e3000 - 0x35a61fff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x35af0000 - 0x35b9efff  Message armv7  <b8221d43401d315fb84398b7aa570fc1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x35ba9000 - 0x35bd5fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x36039000 - 0x36081fff  CoreMedia armv7  <eb1f503312be3c93b07b2d0d25177000> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x361c7000 - 0x362b8fff  QuartzCore armv7  <a2afbe6483683d05ad51b106f98776e2> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x362bd000 - 0x362c4fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <0703f561f9a038b6850d6e93bba7e5f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x36319000 - 0x36336fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x36390000 - 0x36393fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x36399000 - 0x363d4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x363e6000 - 0x3644afff  MessageUI armv7  <b74d79ea691a35ada276f063b7217a20> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x3644b000 - 0x36451fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3645a000 - 0x36465fff  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x3647e000 - 0x364c7fff  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x365a8000 - 0x365c7fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x365de000 - 0x3661cfff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x3661d000 - 0x36642fff  OpenCL armv7  <ec915bfc3f7633dda61b5fc87459119b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x36646000 - 0x3669efff  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3679b000 - 0x367a7fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x367ed000 - 0x367f4fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x367f6000 - 0x368a0fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x368cc000 - 0x368cdfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <66e985f3eea03ef08afb7cf4c153f76e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x368ce000 - 0x368dbfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x368dc000 - 0x369b4fff  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x369b9000 - 0x369c3fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x369d8000 - 0x36aeffff  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x36b21000 - 0x36b27fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36b2b000 - 0x36c70fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x36d07000 - 0x371a9fff  UIKit armv7  <d72bcc68e76a3a55a963590cdcffe8cd> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x371aa000 - 0x371adfff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x371d4000 - 0x371d8fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3725e000 - 0x37274fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <7ac5560851ce3cb3981068092074b409> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x37311000 - 0x3738afff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x37391000 - 0x37453fff  Celestial armv7  <2a59586b0ae937c3b25fe526924aa885> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x37454000 - 0x37457fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x37492000 - 0x374aafff  iAd armv7  <9e9184ed0077317a97b879c3df950316> /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
0x3752d000 - 0x37543fff  EAP8021X armv7  <fffe86a22bc434a6ae84f23bfecef9d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3758f000 - 0x375a6fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <bd20a05587783a8e9596eef1d3615ea7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x376f8000 - 0x37777fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x37793000 - 0x377ddfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x377de000 - 0x377effff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x37b89000 - 0x37b9dfff  PersistentConnection armv7  <65682d21486836a3aa3e17b9461e7b3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x37b9e000 - 0x37b9efff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37ce5000 - 0x37cecfff  StoreKit armv7  <1bc0c05f99a8309d90476b42263e3487> /System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/StoreKit
0x37d07000 - 0x37d0ffff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC_BREAKPOINT on iOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837838/exc-breakpoint-on-ios5)

Comment: @trojanfoe: that question has no accepted answer, though...

Comment: @sergio It did have a suggested fix though, but no update was posted, so who knows if it worked or not.

Comment: @trojanfoe - I'm not running debug on the computer, as per the guy who left a comment. I get this running an Ad-Hoc application directly on the iPad. In Simulator & Debug the app doesn't crash.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding some code? What I can see from your stack trace is that the last statement of yours (I guess) which is executed is:

```
+[MKStoreManager setObject:forKey:] (MKStoreManager.m:123)
```

I think you could set a breakpoint there and inspect which values are being passed over...

Comment: Here is the code of the app delegate: http://pastie.org/private/ex1qx8cqs9avrvowsujg

Comment: The error happens inside the MKStoreKit framework and unfortunately I cannot help further. Possibly the plist is not getting copied over to the device (I am just guessing). But the only chance you have to clear this out is stepping through the program and see which conditions causes the crash. It will not take long given your stack trace; just put a breakpoint on your delegate first line and debug (with your device selected, not the simulator)...

Comment: Ok I've contacted the guy who developed MKStoreKit and will revert back here once I have more feedback from him directly.

Comment: I am personally using MKStorekit on a project right now and have no problems. The problem is your project, not MKStorekit.

Comment: The exception is too vague that it looks like your development machine will get such problems for a majority of cases. EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) is a very generic error that is not associated with MKStoreKit. The only advise I can give you is to try reinstalling your Xcode

Comment: I am having this SIGTRAP error right now with a live app using MKStoreKit. It crashes in the same place. I am beside myself and have no idea of how to fix this or what has gone wrong. The code functioned fine until a couple of days ago. I think 7.0.3 brought up an issue that I had not seen before, but I do not know what to do with this error. Did you end up discovering the problem?

Comment: @JPK no I did not ever find the solution to this. I ended up having to redo my logic so as to avoid this crash.

Comment: Good job. My key was Nil!.!.!.!